# 14.04 stalls on boot up, waits for button press

Tags: 14.04, boot, startup

Title says it all. When I boot up, the computer shows the Lenovo logo and says "Press Enter to interrupt normal start up", (which doesn't work, and I also can't figure out how to enter the BIOS)and then hangs on a black screen with a white cursor. I can't actually type anything, but as soon as I hit a key, it goes to The Ubuntu logo and follows through just fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Don't reinstall; I think it's your computer itself. Did you press the keys as soon as you turned the computer on?

Comment: I forgot to mention, this only started a month and a half ago. I got a new desk, and moved everything over, which obviously involves unplugging everything. It started up right around this time, although I suppose it could have been a perfectly timed coincidence.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you hit F2 or F12 during boot? I also have a Lenovo with Secure Boot/UEFI enabled and was always able to hit either one of those to be taken to BIOS or boot menu.

Comment: Nothing, I can't do anything of the sort. I've tried escape, F1, F2, F12, enter (like it says), space, click, the list goes on and on. Even thrashing every possible key doesn't work, and everyone knows that fixes any computer problem that could possibly exist. I have everything backed up, so I'm considered re-installing the system, as this is still the first Linux system I've ever had, and in my first little while with it I'm sure I completely littered it with crap.

Comment: If you have everything backed up then it might be a good option to give a shot. The trick could be if you have USB boot higher in priority than SSD/HDD.